# schtasks command - strange folder/path behaviour

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am currently trying to use the schtasks command to change scheduled tasks on a Windows 2008 server. I have successfully updated a task which resides within the 'top level' folder path under Task Scheduler Library, however when I attempt to edit a scheduled task which resides within a subfolder, schtasks cannot find the task but I cannot see why as schtasks can find the job when I run a query using the same path??

The output below will explain better.

**Working**

```
C:\>schtasks /query /TN "\Batch Finalisation Time Test"

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
Batch Finalisation Time Test             26/11/2015 19:30:00    Ready

C:\>schtasks /change /ED "30/11/2015" /ET "23:59:59" /TN "\Batch Finalisation Time Test" /ru ""
SUCCESS: The parameters of scheduled task "\Batch Finalisation Time Test" have been changed.
```

**Not Working**

```
C:\>schtasks /query /TN "\Elite Maintenance Jobs\Batch Finalisation Time"

Folder: \Elite Maintenance Jobs
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
Batch Finalisation Time                  26/11/2015 19:30:00    Ready

C:\>schtasks /change /ED "30/11/2015" /ET "23:59:59" /TN "\Elite Maintenance Jobs\Batch Finalisation Time" /ru ""
ERROR: The specified path is invalid.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that this seems to be caused by task configuration (General tab), once the "Configure for:" dropdown was updated to 'Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2' the task could then be amended successfully via the schtasks command.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  My tasks are all configured for 'Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2' but schtasks can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turned out I also needed to be running as Administrator.  This command worked from a normal prompt:

```
schtasks /query /tn "\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsColorSystem\Calibration Loader"
```

but a similar command to access a task I created in a new folder which I also created only worked from an elevated prompt.